# Snakemake: 'Unexpected keyword notebook in rule definition' when trying to implement Jupyter notebooks

Tags: snakemake

I've been trying to use the Snakemake Jupyter notebook functionality for Snakemake, using the example given in the Snakemake wiki as a template (see: [Jupyter notebook integration](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#jupyter-notebook-integration)).

However when trying to run my Snakefile I get the error: `Unexpected keyword notebook in rule definition (Snakefile, line 62)`. From my experience with Snakemake these kind of errors are often caused by inconsistent indentation, however I have been unable to solve this problem that way.

Any help is much appreciated

Full Snakefile:

```
# CONFIG
configfile: "config.yaml"

# PIPELINE RULES.
#include: "rules/preperation/get_remote_genome.snakefile"
include: "rules/preperation/get_remote_annovar_dbs.snakefile"
include: "rules/preperation/bwa_index.snakefile"
include: "rules/fastqc.snakefile"
include: "rules/trimmomatic.snakefile"
include: "rules/bwa_mem.snakefile"
include: "rules/samtools_sort.snakefile"
include: "rules/marked_duplicates.snakefile"
include: "rules/bamtools_split.snakefile"
include: "rules/samtools_mpileup.snakefile"
include: "rules/varscan.snakefile"
include: "rules/concat_vcf.snakefile"
include: "rules/annovar.snakefile"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("runs/{sample}/results/results_notebook.html",
               sample=config["samples"])

rule jupyter_to_html:
    input:
        "runs/{sample}/results/results_notebook.ipynb"
    output:
        "runs/{sample}/results/results_notebook.html"
    shell:
        "jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html {input}"

rule jupyter_report:
    input:
        expand("runs/{{sample}}/results/{{sample}}_{num}_fastqc.html",
               num = ["R1", "R2"]),
        expand("runs/{{sample}}/results/{{sample}}.{genome_build}_multianno.txt",
               genome_build = config["genome_build"])
    output:
        "runs/{sample}/results/results_notebook.ipynb"
    log:
        notebook = "runs/{sample}/results/results_notebook.ipynb"
    notebook:
        config["notebook"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notebook integration is available from [Snakemake 5.10](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/history.html#id18) onwards. Maybe your version of Snakemake is < 5.10?

Comment: Ah, that explains everything. I'm working remotely on my university's network and had recently switched from using a virtual environment to using their locally installed version. Thank you!

Comment: Use conda! Create a project environment, add dependencies in a requirement file, put code on git(hub) and replicate that environment wherever you are. Anyway, glad to hear you resolved the issue!